# Error when using QuickBooks PHP DevKit examples

Tags: php, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

I have successfully setup the Quickbooks PHP DevKit, but I am currently trying to run the example_customer_add script with my sandbox.  When I do, I get the following error:

> Notice:  Undefined variable: Context in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/quickbooks-php/test_qb.php on line 54

I've tried to track down the `$Context` variable, but it is used all over the place, and I'm unsure of where it being set, etc...

Any help is appreciated!  Thanks!

**EDIT**

I'm just using the script included in the docs folder of the Quickbooks PHP DevKit:

```
<?php
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/config.php';
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/views/header.tpl.php';
?>

<pre>

<?php

$CustomerService = new QuickBooks_IPP_Service_Customer();

$Customer = new QuickBooks_IPP_Object_Customer();
$Customer->setTitle('Ms');
$Customer->setGivenName('Shannon');
$Customer->setMiddleName('B');
$Customer->setFamilyName('Palmer');
$Customer->setDisplayName('Shannon B Palmer ' . mt_rand(0, 1000));

// Terms (e.g. Net 30, etc.)
$Customer->setSalesTermRef(4);

// Phone #
$PrimaryPhone = new QuickBooks_IPP_Object_PrimaryPhone();
$PrimaryPhone->setFreeFormNumber('860-532-0089');
$Customer->setPrimaryPhone($PrimaryPhone);

// Mobile #
$Mobile = new QuickBooks_IPP_Object_Mobile();
$Mobile->setFreeFormNumber('860-532-0089');
$Customer->setMobile($Mobile);

// Fax #
$Fax = new QuickBooks_IPP_Object_Fax();
$Fax->setFreeFormNumber('860-532-0089');
$Customer->setFax($Fax);

// Bill address
$BillAddr = new QuickBooks_IPP_Object_BillAddr();
$BillAddr->setLine1('72 E Blue Grass Road');
$BillAddr->setLine2('Suite D');
$BillAddr->setCity('Mt Pleasant');
$BillAddr->setCountrySubDivisionCode('MI');
$BillAddr->setPostalCode('48858');
$Customer->setBillAddr($BillAddr);

// Email
$PrimaryEmailAddr = new QuickBooks_IPP_Object_PrimaryEmailAddr();
$Customer->setPrimaryEmailAddr($PrimaryEmailAddr);

if ($resp = $CustomerService->add($Context, $realm, $Customer))
{
  print('Our new customer ID is: [' . $resp . '] (name "' . $Customer-    >getDisplayName() . '")');
}
else
{
  print($CustomerService->lastError($Context));
}


?>

</pre>
<?php
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/views/footer.tpl.php';
```

The quickbooks_oauth table looks like this after attempting to connect:

```
'1', 'DO_NOT_CHANGE_ME', '12345', 'qyprdaX1yo1uYqu3GU8xxPvs8raoTss2ZVRBE3fHWy7qZdAB', 'IWZHlW2e956sqR9GVIxa2JOU82NdSrJixZLpb3af', 'KNwiKE2bUXtqFqJ/Vb0NhjzBGYMXwRRcT9xtFOQiV6F8aEgUoqGzA7aheRLPJ/z6EPYy1ZS4e6ZuVpteBaQtxc5H0cN5VcCmWLfj+lryaCpLgw8mGK5+E/Muv2wJ+3UwbOyqVstU+pYQw/yNgFKhfSuA3lOgjgqctuO6ZpMK1wWr42IycA05QrJuOB4+LQ==', 'rCj1V3zl4Jj5mHgTw+BPCPN7SDcJkzLQPWb1tyerEXedsQB0WsZ+caMCBafS+hfN3ECZl3mfNDSyIqKDK+t8RSEAKyFWwRSPOh3UcWDCDEhXrTSUddmKhoIq6pL6yVtNEyETyNtfMaKYN+U6uIwSEMKZB/4IUjK8c0GP5KhoKSl0dv+Bp9w=', '1391140255', 'QBO', NULL, '2015-06-04 19:57:58', '2015-06-04 19:58:36', '2015-06-04 19:58:36'
```

Comment: It's an `E_NOTICE` so you can ignore it if you want. It just means a variable is being referenced when it's not defined.

Comment: However, I'm fairly confident that variable needs to be defined in order for the script to work.

Comment: The next step would be to get an IDE like Netbeans (which is free) and see if you can find line 54

Comment: Post your code. How can we help you if we can't see what you're doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted is missing several lines at the top of the script. Look at the example on GitHub:

https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php/blob/master/docs/partner_platform/example_app_ipp_v3/example_customer_add.php#L3

There are two `require_once` statements that you are missing. `$Context` is defined in those required files.

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/config.php';
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/views/header.tpl.php';
```

Fix your code so that you're using the example code completely, and making sure those required files actually get included.

If you continue to have trouble, please post your updated code.

You can see where `$Context` gets defined here:

- https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php/blob/master/docs/partner_platform/example_app_ipp_v3/config.php#L110

Note that *you must be connected to QuickBooks to run the example*. I'm assuming you have clicked the "Connect to QuickBooks" button and gotten connected already... right?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Keith.  I had that part of the code in there, but for some reason didn't paste it over.  I've edited the answer to reflect this.  I had thought I was connected, but on reexamining it, I've noticed it still has the red box saying I'm not connected, even though when I click on the button it goes through the process and says I have successfully connected.  Any ideas on why this would happen?

Comment: What do the records in your quickbooks_oauth table look like?

Comment: Edited post to show what the table looks like.  It doesn't show the column labels, but I'm guessing you are familiar with what they are suppose to be.

Comment: @jldavis76  That definitely looks correct to me. I'm unsure why it would not show you as connected -- you may have to go through some code and see what you can track down. Try disconnecting and reconnecting first. Is your server date/time correct? What timezone are you in?

Comment: @jldavis76   If you're in California, how can your system time be set to 7pm+?

Comment: Palmer Honestly, I'm not sure why it was set to that.  I'm in the Pacific timezone, and I have corrected that and attempted to connect again with the same result.  It's odd, because the pop up box that opens says I have successfully connected, but nothing changes.  Any other ideas on what I can look for?  Thanks for your time so far!

Comment: Still says no connection after refreshing the page?  Are your tokens development, or live tokens? Are you using the sandbox QBO, or a live QBO?

Comment: I did a clean clone of the repo, and set up a new app, and now it connects just fine.  I'm not sure what was going wrong, but I don't want to take up anymore of your time.  Thanks for the help!